# Java JOptionPane.showInputDialog with constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, joptionpane

First post, I hope I don't seem to n00bish.

I am in a Java class and am stuck with a problem.

The requirement is to make a class (`Contact`) which has getters and a constructor for `name`, `email` and `phoneNumber`. Then a test class (`TestContact`) which has a `while loop` that keeps prompting the user because the hit `OK` and didn't type anything, hit Enter or the name is over 21 characters.

Also, the three variables I need (name, email and phone number) are to be entered in the same input box (parsed by the whitespace between).

I can't seem to figure out how to get it working. I have many bugs.

Firstly, I'm not sure how I can setup the array and then split it with the whitespace then use that array to set my variable & getters (hope that makes sense?).

Also, the program keeps crashing because of `NullPointerException` in the array and array index out of bounds exception.

Contact class:

```
public class Contact 
{
    //Initiating variables
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String eMail;
    //Constructor
    public Contact()
    {
        this.name = getName();
        this.phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();
        this.eMail = getEMail();
    }
    //Getter for name variable
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    //Getter for phoneNumber variable
    public String getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    //Getter for eMail variable
    public String getEMail()
    {
        return eMail;
    }
}
```

TestContact class:

```
public class testContact 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Contact myContact = new Contact();
        String userInput;
        String noUserInput;
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        do  
        {   
            String[] phrases = userInput.split(" ");
            String name = phrases[0] + " " + phrases[1];
            String phoneNumber = phrases[2];
            String eMail = phrases[3];
            if (!userInput.equals(""))
                {   
                    if (name.length() > 21)
                    {
                        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm sorry but your name is too long.\nPlease enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
                        String[] phrases = userInput.split(" ");
                        String name = phrases[0] + " " + phrases[1];
                        String phoneNumber = phrases[2];
                        String eMail = phrases[3];
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+myContact.getName()+"\nPhone Number: "+myContact.getPhoneNumber()+"\nE-Mail: "+myContact.getEMail());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+name+"\nPhone Number: "+phoneNumber+"\nE-Mail: "+eMail);
                    }
                }
            while ((userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm sorry but you didn't enter anything.\nPlease enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ")) == null)
            {   
                String[] phrases = userInput.split(" ");
                String name = phrases[0] + " " + phrases[1];
                String phone = phrases[2];
                String eMail = phrases[3];
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+myContact.getName()+"\nPhone Number: "+myContact.getPhoneNumber()+"\nE-Mail: "+myContact.getEMail());
            }
        }while(userInput != null);
    }
}
```

***NOTE*** 
I changed around my TestContact class to make it a bit nicer see below. My only issue is how to set the method with what I parsed from the string array and put into string variables. How would I set those for the constructor??

```
public class testContact 
{
    static String userInput;
    static Contact myContact = new Contact();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        do  
        {   
            parsing(initialInput());
            if (!userInput.equals(""))
                {   
                    if (myContact.getName().length() > 21)
                    {
                        parsing(nameLengthErrorInput());
                        output();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output();
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                parsing(nullErrorInput());
                output();
            }
        }while(userInput != null);
    }
    public static String initialInput()
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        return userInput;
    }
    public static String nameLengthErrorInput()
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm sorry but your name is too long.\nPlease enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        return userInput;
    }
    public static String nullErrorInput()
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm sorry but you didn't enter anything.\nPlease enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        return userInput;
    }
    public static void output()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+myContact.getName()+"\nPhone Number: "+myContact.getPhoneNumber()+"\nE-Mail: "+myContact.getEMail());
    }
    public static void parsing(String userInput)
    {
        String[] phrases = userInput.split(" ");
        String name = phrases[0] + " " + phrases[1];
        String phoneNumber = phrases[2];
        String eMail = phrases[3];
    }
}
```

My issue is now sole in the parsing() method.

Comment: *"Also, the three variables I need (name, email and phone number) are to be entered in the same input box (parsed by the whitespace between)."* I would think that this is the wrong approach and increases the complexity to an almost unmanageable level.  Instead, consider prompting for each value separately...

Comment: Not allowed. The assignment is to have one input dialog and parse out the name, phone number, and e-mail by separating whitespace & to keep asking if the user hits enter with no data or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary errors...

### First...

In the `Contact` constructor, you assigning the variables back to themselves...

```
public Contact() {
    this.name = getName();
    this.phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();
    this.eMail = getEMail();
}
```

This is pretty much the same as saying...

```
public Contact() {
    this.name = this.name;
    this.phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber;
    this.eMail = this.eMail;
}
```

The result is the same...

### Second...

You're getting a `NullPointerException` here...

```
if (myContact.getName().length() > 21) {
```

Because the value of `Contact#getName` has never been assigned (a valid) value

### Suggestions...

#### First...

I would suggest changing the `Contact` constructor to require values to passed to it...

```
public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber, String eMail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.eMail = eMail;
}
```

This will mean that...

```
static Contact myContact = new Contact();
```

Will no longer compile, but you can change it to

```
static Contact myContact;
```

instead...

#### Second...

I would suggest changing your `parsing` method to return a `Contact`, for example...

```
public static Contact parsing(String userInput) {
    Contact contact = null;
    if (userInput != null && userInput.trim().length() > 0) {
        String[] phrases = userInput.split(" ");
        if (phrases.length == 4) {
            String name = phrases[0] + " " + phrases[1];
            String phoneNumber = phrases[2];
            String eMail = phrases[3];
            contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber, eMail);
        }
    }
    return contact;
}
```

You should also be guarding against invalid input as well.

This means you would need to assign the result each time you use one of your parsing methods...

```
myContact = parsing(initialInput());
```

#### Third...

Each time a user fails to enter what you need, you should simply display an error message and make enter new information, you're kind of trying to do that, but you're not taking advantage of your existing error checking to re-validate the input...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String errorMsg = "";
    do {
        myContact = parsing(getInput(errorMsg));
        if (myContact != null) {
            if (myContact.getName().length() > 21) {
                myContact = null;
                errorMsg = "<html>I'm sorry but your name is too long.<br>";
            }
        } else {
            errorMsg = "<html>I'm sorry but you didn't enter anything.<br>";
        }
    } while (myContact == null);
    output();
}

public static String getInput(String errorMsg) {
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(errorMsg + "Please enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
    return userInput;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It doesn't look like the getter methods are being used though. Also, i'm not allowed to use HTML:/ But this gave me some things to think through!

Comment: Got it all working, had to change the code around a bit; but you gave me the right direction! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

So I just submitted my lab and this is my final solution

Contact class:

```
public class Contact 
{
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String eMail;
    public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber, String eMail) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getEMail()
    {
        return eMail;
    }
}
```

TestContact class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class testContact 
{
    static Contact myContact;
    static Boolean exitBool = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        myContact = parsing(initialInput());
        do  
        {               
            if (myContact != null)
                {   
                    if (myContact.getName().length() > 21)
                    {
                        myContact = parsing(nameLengthErrorInput());
                        exitBool = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exitBool = true;
                    }
                }
            else if (myContact == null)
            {
                myContact = parsing(nullErrorInput());
                exitBool = false;
                //output();
            }
        }while(exitBool == false);
        output();
    }    

    public static String initialInput()
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        return userInput;
    }

    public static String nameLengthErrorInput()
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm sorry but your name is too long.\nPlease enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        return userInput;
    }

    public static String nullErrorInput()
    {
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm sorry but you didn't enter anything.\nPlease enter your First and Last Name, Phone Number, & E-mail: ");
        return userInput;
    }

    public static void output()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: "+myContact.getName()+"\nPhone Number: "+myContact.getPhoneNumber()+"\nE-Mail: "+myContact.getEMail());
    }

    public static Contact parsing(String userInput) {
        Contact contact = null;
        if (userInput != null && userInput.trim().length() > 0) {
            String[] phrases = userInput.split(" ");
                String name = phrases[0] + " " + phrases[1];
                String phoneNumber = phrases[2];
                String eMail = phrases[3];
                contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber, eMail);
        }
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, it's discouraged for doing this, apart from just been a massive code dump, it doesn't provide information action about why this solution solves the problem at hand...